# Update values of non NaN positions in a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to update the values of non-NaN entries in a dataframe column

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np
d = {
    't': [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1],
    'input': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4],
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
    'value': [0.1, 0.2, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The data for updating the `value` column is in a list

```
new_value = [10, 15, 1, 18]
```

I could get the non-NaN entries in column `value`

```
df["value"].notnull()
```

I'm not sure how to assign the new values.

Suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[df["value"].notna(), 'value'] = new_value
```

By `df["value"].notna()` you select the rows where `value` is not NAN, then you specify the column (value in this case). It is important that the number of rows selected by the condition matches the number of values in `new_value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first identify the index which have nan values.

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np
d = {
    't': [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1],
    'input': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4],
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
    'value': [0.1, 0.2, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
r, _ = np.where(df.isna())
new_value = [10, 15, 18] # There are only 3 nans
df.loc[r,'value'] = new_value
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   t  input type  value
0  0      2    A    0.1
1  1      2    A    0.2
2  2      2    A   10.0
3  0      2    B   20.0
4  2      2    B    2.0
5  0      2    B    3.0
6  1      4    A   30.0
```